# One has an end; the other has both

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Two words you hear, sound same to the ear,
>   But their spelling and meaning differ.
>   One has an end; the other has both,
>   They are seldom uttered together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

> tale and tail
>  a tale (story) has an end to it, and a tail has two ends
> **Revised:**
> a tail has an end, while a tale has both a beginning and an end.

Comment: You got the words right! Just need to switch the reasons, though. Think along the lines of what is an end and what is its opposite.

Comment: I am not sure I am getting it, but have revised my answer.

Comment: Great, you nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

What about:

> brake and break
>  Brake(ing) has a single ending point.
>  After a break, both parts have ends.

Comment: I like that, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly

> ADZE and ADS

Because

> ADZE - a tool used to shape wood, has a pointy end like a chisel
>  ADS - advertisements, an ad has a beginning and an end
>  I'm sure they exist, but I have never heard or seen ads for an adze, let alone said them in the same sentence until now.